# Gerschgorin Theorem singularity proof

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I know how to prove the Gerschgorin Theorem but how exactly would one show that there are no values of $\mu$ s.t. $\mu<0$ for which $A-\mu B$ is singular where

$$ A=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        2 & -2 & 0 \\
        -3 & 5 & 0 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$ and

$$ B=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        2 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 2 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 & 2 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: You have no accepted answers. Please read about accepting answers [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Comment: What are you having trouble with, exactly? Compute $A-\mu B$ and apply the Gershgorin circle theorem to $A-\mu B$.